# How can I store and print the top 20% feature names and scores?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

The following code reads in cleaned-up titanic data, prints out all the features and scores

```
import csv 
import numpy as np

data = np.genfromtxt('titanic.csv',dtype=float, delimiter=',', names=True)

feature_names = np.array(data.dtype.names)
feature_names = feature_names[[ 0,1,2,3,4]] 

data = np.genfromtxt('plants.csv',dtype=float, delimiter=',', skip_header=1)

_X = data[:, [0,1,2,3,4]] 
#Return a flattened array required by scikit-learn fit for 2nd argument
_y = np.ravel(data[:,[5]])

from sklearn import feature_selection
fs = feature_selection.SelectPercentile(feature_selection.chi2, percentile=20)
X_train_fs = fs.fit_transform(_X, _y)

print feature_names, '\n', fs.scores_
```

Result:

```
['A'  'B' 'C' 'D' 'E']
[  4.7324711   89.1428574   70.23474577   7.02447375  52.42447817]
```

What I want to do is to capture the top 20% of features, and store the names and scores in an array I can then sort by scores. This will assist me in larger features set dimension reduction. Why am I getting all 5 features, how can I fix that, and how can I store and print the top 20% feature names and scores?

Answer (score 7):

You are almost there. The scores are indeed stored in `fs.scores_`; however, the eventually selected features (according to the percentile you've set) are stored in `X_train_fs`. Try to print the shape of `X_train_fs` and it should have a column number smaller than 5.

The code below may help you in the sorting part:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import feature_selection

_X = np.random.random((100,5))
_y = np.random.random(100)
fs = feature_selection.SelectPercentile(feature_selection.chi2, percentile=20)
X_train_fs = fs.fit_transform(_X, _y)
feature_names = ['a','b','c','d','e']

print 'All features:', feature_names
print 'Scores of these features:', fs.scores_
print '***Features sorted by score:', [feature_names[i] for i in np.argsort(fs.scores_)[::-1]]
print 'Peeking into first few samples (before and after):'
print _X[:10]
print X_train_fs[:10]
```

Output:

```
All features: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
Scores of these features: [ 17.08834764  13.97983442  18.0124008   17.79594679  14.77178022]
***Features sorted by score: ['c', 'd', 'a', 'e', 'b']
Peeking into first few samples (before and after):
[[ 0.34808143  0.79142591  0.75333429  0.69246515  0.29079619]
 [ 0.81726059  0.93065583  0.01183974  0.66227077  0.82216764]
 [ 0.8791751   0.21764549  0.06147596  0.01156631  0.22077268]
 [ 0.91079625  0.58496956  0.68548851  0.55365907  0.78447282]
 [ 0.24489774  0.88725231  0.32411121  0.09189075  0.83266337]
 [ 0.1041106   0.98683633  0.22545763  0.98577525  0.41408367]
 [ 0.09014649  0.51216454  0.62158409  0.94874742  0.81915236]
 [ 0.32828772  0.05461745  0.43343171  0.59472169  0.83159784]
 [ 0.33792151  0.47963184  0.08690499  0.31566743  0.26170533]
 [ 0.10012106  0.36240434  0.86687847  0.64894175  0.51167487]]
[[ 0.75333429]
 [ 0.01183974]
 [ 0.06147596]
 [ 0.68548851]
 [ 0.32411121]
 [ 0.22545763]
 [ 0.62158409]
 [ 0.43343171]
 [ 0.08690499]
 [ 0.86687847]]
```

Comment: One more way to get feature names could be to use the get_support method.

```print("feature_names:", [feature_names[i] for i in fs.get_support(indices = True)])```